# Spacing between <li>'s

Tags: html, css

So I'm a little stumped. I'm trying to make a page to display images. I want there to be 5 images per row spaced with maximum amount when the window is at max width (~950 px), but I want them to get closer as you make it smaller and then, when there's 0 px between them, there will only be 4 images per row, and that will continue until a specific width. Kind of like Instagram, but I don't want the pictures to get smaller. Here's what I have:

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <img src="0.png">
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>
      <img src="1.png">
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>
      <img src="2.png">
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type:  none;
}

ul li
{
    display: inline;
}

//the images are also float left, so they are horizontal
```

Basically, as you can see, I have nothing and I don't really know what to do. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you put a `min-width` on the image `<li>`s?

Comment: Are answers with <table> permitted?

Comment: @JimW No. No. No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: Remove the whitespace between the `<li>` elements.

Comment: @iambriansreed But images can be data, it could be a table of image data, no?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No because I want it to be flexible. I want the distance between the two images to decrease to 0 when I make the window smaller, but before that to be apart.

Comment: @JimW Clearly it's not.

Comment: @iambriansreed Sorry, how is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do me a favor and try this fix (I know there is an obnoxious invisible-spacing bug related to `li`s written on newlines in the HTML, not sure if it applies to UL's in order too but it's worth a shot) --

```
<ul><li><img src="0.png"></li></ul><ul><li><img src="1.png"></li></ul><ul><li><img src="2.png"></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may get you closer to where you want to go:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type:  none;
    min-width:450px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
  <li> <img src="0.png" width="150" height="50"> </li>
  <li> <img src="1.png" width="150" height="50"> </li>
  <li> <img src="2.png" width="150" height="50"> </li>
  <li> <img src="0.png" width="150" height="50"> </li>
  <li> <img src="1.png" width="150" height="50"> </li>
  <li> <img src="2.png" width="150" height="50"> </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It is more "proper" markup to put all the images into one list, and opens the door for setting a hard minimum width on the ul but a % on the li... which is what makes the whitespace vary with the window sizing. I am not sure if this gets you all the way there, but hopefully it will help!

Comment: They're overlaying each other. But I do like how it stretches when I expand the page.

Comment: ^What they said: http://jsfiddle.net/T7ryt/

Answer (score 0):

Your unordered list should look like this:

```
<ul><li><img src="0.png"></li><li><img src="1.png"></li><li><img src="2.png"></li></ul>
```

Super unconventional, but it works.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QMs93/

Comment: I didn't do that, the person who edited my post did. I did it the way you wrote it.

Comment: Oh ok, well check out my edited response with a fiddle. Should help!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/AgLMp/1

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-width: 950px;
    min-width: 600px;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000/00ffff&text=Image+1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/00ff00/ff00ff&text=Image+2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/0000ff/ffff00&text=Image+3" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do his thing of having one less column as the width narrows.

Comment: Wow really close. Although if I make it smaller so that there are 2 boxes in each row, I want them to be spread out as well. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/AgLMp/2

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No so when I make the window smaller, there will be only 3 boxes. But I want them to be spaced from each other all the way. What you had the first time was good, although when I made the screen smaller, there would be 2 images but I want them to be spaced from each other as the initial 3 were.

Answer (score 0):

like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fqTsN/

remove the `float:left` from your pictures by the way! I fixed that too (it's horizontal without `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

your best and fastest bet for more control is to use media queries, or you could also use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said:

```
<ul>
 <li>Stuff</li>
  <li> Other Stuff</li>
  </ul>
```